# Develop Add-In for Outlook Pre

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I try to develop a Add-In for Outlook Pre with Teams Toolkit which will work perfectly fine for normal Outlook. But I can't make it that the Add-In is visible in the new Pre Version which can be enabled within Outlook.

Any hints or tipps for that?

Best regards,

Lars

I created a task pane Add-In via Teams Toolkit.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for trying out the unified app manifest. Really appreciate your early adoption.

At this time, "New Outlook" does not show outlook extensions coming from unified app manifest. We are working on it and will make an announcement when that support is available.

Until then, please continue to use OWA or Old Outlook for consuming Outlook Extensions from unified app manifest.